# How to create table of array based on textboxes?

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, visual-studio

I have NxM textboxes created dynamicly.
User fill textboxes with integer.
I need to create table NxM with data which was puted into Textboxes.
I need it to do matrix calculations.

How can I do that? Can I do this using for each loop?

I have this code which gives me NxM Textboxes:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= verticalCount; i++) 
        {

            if (i == verticalCount)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < horizontalValue; j++)
                {
                    var xEnd = 100 + 80 * verticalCount; ;
                    var yEnd = 100 + 60 * j;
                    var textBoxNM = new TextBox();
                    textBoxNM.Name = string.Format("TextBox_{0}_{1}", i, j); 
                    textBoxNM.Location = new Point(xEnd, yEnd);
                    textBoxNM.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 25);
                    Step2.Controls.Add(textBoxNM);

                    string end = string.Format("result = ", i + 1);
                    newLabel(end, xEnd - 60, yEnd, Step2);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < horizontalValue; j++) //
                {
                    var x = 20 + 80 * i;
                    var y = 100 + 60 * j;

                    if (j < horizontalValue)
                    {
                        newTextbox(x, y, Step2);
                        string nbr = string.Format("x{0}", i + 1);
                        newLabel(nbr, x + 50, y, Step2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I have code written in c++ and I'm trying to create windows application of it.

Thanks!

edit:

```
public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var verticalCount = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.Text);
        var horizontalValue = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.Text);

        int[,] tbArray;
        tbArray = new int[,] { { horizontalValue , verticalCount } };

        foreach (Control ShouldBeTextBox in this.Controls)
        {
            if (ShouldBeTextBox is TextBox)
            {
                if (ShouldBeTextBox != null)
                {
                    int x = horizontalValue;
                    int y = verticalCount;
                    var tag = ShouldBeTextBox.Tag as int[];
                    string a = Convert.ToString(tag);
                    MessageBox.Show(a);
                    tbArray[tag[x], tag[y]] = Convert.ToInt32(ShouldBeTextBox.Text);
                }
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Fill all parameters");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us the relevant parts of your current code.

Comment: Thanks for taking an interest in this! I edited topic.

Comment: Check [DataGridView control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That's not exactly what could help me. I have functions written in c++ which do calculation on matrix and I only want to transfer this functions and use it as a method in c#. Functions like searching pivot columns, multiplying columns etc... And I want the whole application to use TextBoxes, Labels and Buttons.

Comment: You can use DataGridView. Also you can use a TableLayoutPanel and add TextBox controls to the table layout panel.

Comment: Can you recommend me some tutorials which can show how to work with DataGridView (regarding what I need described in topic) as I've never used that before. And second question - when I use DataGridView does that mean my table will look like from Excel?

Comment: DGV is the natural choice for this. Or put the textboxes into a TableLayoutPanel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you could do is when creating a textbox give them matrix co-ordinates as a tag. Send the i and j to your newTextbox method and do something like

```
theNewTextBox.Tag = new int[] {i, j};
```

Later when you need to get values into your matrix array you can do something like this:

```
foreach(Control c in Step2.Controls)
{
   Textbox tb = c as TextBox;
   if (tb != null)
   {
       var tag = tb.Tag as int[];
       theMatrixArray[tag[0], tag[1]] = tb.Text; // Or parse it to int if you can't have it in text
   }
}
```

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: I did just like you write, but I have problem with convert string to int, could you please tell me where the problem is? I edited topic, please check.

Comment: Right now it gives error "var could not be found' but when I change var to int it gives different error 'Use unassigned local variable theMatrixArray'

Comment: well this was just sample... I assumed you had a two-dimensional array to store the matrix. any array or a two dimensional list would do. You just have to initialise one, something like: int[ , ] theMatrixArray = new int[verticalValue, horizontalValue]; 

and since it's an int array your assignment of value would have to be: theMatrixArray[tag[0], tag[1]] = int.Parse(tb.Text.Trim());

Comment: I've seen the edit of your code and I fear you misunderstood somewhat the foreach loop with the matrix is supposed to be inside a method in which you want to extract values from textboxes into the matrix. the matrix (in this case theMatrixArray) needs to be initialised before the foreach loop. it is the matrix that will contain the values from the TextBox matrix. So somewhere prior to foreach loop you need to do: int[ , ] theMatrixArray = new int[verticalValue, horizontalValue];

Comment: Hi! I've read more about foreach loop and I modyfied my code. When it run, it seems to working fine, but when I close my matrix window form it gives me excepcion "NullExcepction" at line `tbArray[tag[x], tag[y]] = ...`. I'm not sure if I'm right, but it seems like tag value is `null`. What am I doing wrong? Is it something with transfering value from one method to other?

Comment: It might be because you have some Textbox that is not part of the matrix textboxes and therefore is left without a tag. It is simple to fix though. you can add an if (tb.Tag != null) before the theMatrixArray[tag[0], tag[1]] = tb.Text;

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend you use WPF for anything new which is UI related, as it simplifies UI customization in contrast to WinForms. By using something called DataTemplates, you can tell WPF how to represent your data model as a UI element.. this means that you can make WPF create as much Textboxes as necessary. You can also receive value updates to each data model instance via a mechanism called Binding. Finally, a mechanism called ItemsPanelTemplate lets you control the layout of your items. You can use a Grid as a Panel Template for a ListView Control.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I need to do it in c#, as my teammates uses it.

Comment: WPF supports C#.. it is a UI framework that you can use instead of WinForms, combining it with C# logic is natively supported, as WPF is implemented using C#. @Kasia

Comment: The rest do not exist @Fabio